# The 'compactness cardinal' of a space

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, terminology, compactness

I'm looking for references (and a name!) for the following invariant of a topological space $X$:

The least (infinite) cardinal $\kappa$ such that any open cover of $X$ has a subcover of cardinality less than $\kappa$.

For compact spaces, for example, this cardinal is $\aleph_0$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Such spaces have been called *finally* $\kappa$-*compact*. More generally, $X$ is $[\kappa,\lambda]$-*compact* if every open cover of $X$ of cardinality at most $\lambda$ has a subcover of cardinality less than $\kappa$. An $[\omega,\kappa]$-compact space is said to be *initially* $\kappa$-*compact*. Thus, Lindelöf spaces are finally $\omega_1$-compact, and countably compact spaces are initially $\omega$-compact.

Comment: Terminology from an important paper of Alexandroff and Hopf, I believe.  And this is the reason that (in Russian) the term **bicompact** is still used: the spaces which are both finally $\omega_1$-compact and initially $\omega$-compact.

Comment: This is just what I wanted - thanks, Brian!

Comment: @Paul: You’re welcome!